# Grails/Roo for a .Net developer

Tags: c#, java, .net, grails, spring-roo

I am currently picking up Grails and Roo.

The vast majority of training materials appear aimed at new developers or existing Java developers.

Does anyone know of any guides, resources or tips for translating existing development experience with .Net (C#/ASP.Net/Asp.Net MVC)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of, but there may be resources for .Net -> Java, which is probably all you really need. Perhaps tag your question with 'java' as well?

BTW, it's probably worth mentioning which language you're familiar with on .NET.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on tags/information Peter, I've tweaked the question a little.

Answer (score 2):

Have you done much ASP MVC? From the code my friend has shown me it looks very simlar to Grails. Grails is *VERY* easy to use so I would suggest learning that first. I have not learnt Roo as it looks more complicated and I can achieve all I need with Grails very quickly. Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Yes, I use MVC regularly. Thank you for the recommendation on picking up Grails first.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC and Grails both originated from Ruby on Rails - so developing principles are similar for them. I would recomend you to start learning Grails with [this book](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430210450). However getting used to dynamic Groovy after static C# may take some time.

Comment: I have the book, unfortunately it's aimed at new developers and existing Java developers rather than providing cross-over tips from the .Net world.