# Groovy and Grails from C#.Net

Tags: java, c#, asp.net-mvc, grails

I have been primarily using C#.net for around 10 years and I need to learn Grails (and groovy). I have used F#, C++ and Java (not for a while and not web) and all web stuff (MVC, jquery, javascript etc..)

Has anyone got a good method, site, tutorial or some recommendation on the best way to learn Grails based on my experience.

**EDIT** I realise this sort of post is frowned upon (tutorial stuff) but I was actually hoping for a real life story about someone who has done this.

Comment: I have used the tutorial below as well as a lot of trial and error and have a reasonably functioning environment/web app now. Some of this was quite difficult (debugging, ORM's etc.) so I have blogged what I think is a pretty good getting started walkthrough (for .Net devs come grails devs.)  http://www.worthalook.net/2014/08/grails-for-dot-net-developers

Answer (score 1):

Pluralsight has a Video course: [Introduction to Grails](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/grails-introduction) by [Dan Bunker](http://pluralsight.com/training/Authors/Details/dan-bunker).  Their courses are usually pretty good and I think you can still get a free trial to check it out.

There's also more discussion here: [Grails/Roo for a .Net developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052469/grails-roo-for-a-net-developer)

Comment: Thanks that course looks really good.

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/) are excellent and are more likely than other resources to be up-to-date.